# Instantiating Multiple Material Design Components

Tags: javascript, material-components-web

Instantiating a single Material Design Component is straightforward. For example,

```
import { MDCRipple } from "@material/ripple";
const iconButtonRipple = new MDCRipple(document.querySelector(".mdc-icon-button"));
iconButtonRipple.unbounded = true;
```

When there are multiple components, MDC documentation recommends using `querySelectorAll` like this:

```
const iconButtonRipple = [].map.call(
    document.querySelectorAll(".mdc-icon-button"),
    function (el) {
        return new MDCRipple(el);
    }
);
```

However, the above instantiation does not work, and I don't know where to use the `iconButtonRipple.unbounded = true` line in this. The only workaround I have is to assign a special class to every icon button and instantiate it all one by one.

Can someone please help me instantiate this like the one mentioned in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try running this:

```
const ripples = [...document.querySelectorAll(".mdc-icon-button")].map(el => {
  const ripple = new MDCRipple(el);
  ripple.unbounded = true;
});
```

or

```
const ripples = [...document.querySelectorAll(".mdc-icon-button")].map(el => new MDCRipple(el));
ripples.forEach(ripple => {
  ripple.unbounded = true;
});
```